# NodeJS - Reliability

Tags: node.js

One thing I know for a fact is that Node.js shouldn't be used to intensive CPU tasks. Now, imagine that I have a node.js server receiving audio stream from several clients (from MIC). This audio is buffered in a c/c++ addon by doing `memcpy` (which is very fast). But when the `end`event is triggered, this addon will convert "audio-to-command" and send it, to client. This conversion consumes 75ms (max). Can Node.js be considered an reliable solution for this problem? 75ms can be considered an intensive task in node.js? What is the maximum time recommended to blocking operations?

Comment: Hey @carduh, good question! Would you mind tweaking the title a bit to make it more informative? Right now it's a little vague

Comment: @nick anything in specific?

Comment: Well, I could edit it myself but it's your question :) I might suggest something involving blocking/synchronous operations/etc because from what you're describing, it isn't really an issue of reliability but a question of whether Node is the proper solution for this task.

Comment: Please, fell free to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking is not a Node.js way.

You can make this operation asynchronously (in a separate thread), without any blocking, and invoke a callback from your addon when the operation will be finished, so the main node.js thread will not be blocked and will be able to handle other requests.

There are good helpers like AsyncWorker and AsyncQueueWorker in NAN.

https://github.com/nodejs/nan

Also there are C++ libraries to work with WebSockets, so I would think about a direct connection between clients and the addon.